# Get Total Up Time from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

We have an `IssueActivities` table which holds multiple activities for a given IssueID.  Activities include user entries and system entries.  At times, an Issue will be put on 'Hold', in which case there's a system entry in the `IssueActivities` stating so (ex. 'Sub Status has changed from Work in Progress to Down').

**IssueActivities**

```
CREATE TABLE IssueActivities(
IssueID int NOT NULL,
IssueSummary varchar(500),
IssueActivityID int NOT NULL,
IssueActivityTypeID int NOT NULL,
ActivityDate datetime NOT NULL,
TimeSpent bigint NOT NULL,
Notes text NULL,
Notify tinyint NOT NULL);
```

I'm trying to write a SQL statement to calculate the total up-time of an Issue.  Total up-time is the total time that an issue was not in a 'Down' state.

I created a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f56bd/3) to help with querying the data for 1 issue.  I know it says I'm using a SQLite(SQL.js) database but it's actually a SQL Server 2012 DB.  I could not get one of their SQL Studio versions to render my script so I used what I could.

I'm not too sure where to start with this query.  Can it be done in just a sql statement or will a cursor be necessary...I'm not too sure.  I hope it can be done with a sql statement because this will eventually be used in a reporting tool that takes sql statements (not cursors or other sql script).

**Please IGNORE the `TimeSpent` column as it is extremely inaccurate.

Here's a sample of the data:

`IssueID`   `IssueSummary`  `IssueActivityID`   `IssueActivityTypeID`   `ActivityDate`  `TimeSpent` `Notes` `Notify`

32144   'While installing software x, the site is receiving error messages.'    250172  16  2016-06-07 11:13:42.837 600000000   'Issue Entered', 0

32144   'While installing software x, the site is receiving error messages.'    250243  18  2016-06-08 11:13:08.877 600000000   'Sub Status has changed from Work In Progress to Down', 1

32144   'While installing software x, the site is receiving error messages.'    250633  18  2016-06-09 10:02:23.623 600000000   'Sub Status has changed from Down to Hold.'

So that's a basic sample of a issue activities for issue # 32144.  What I'd like to see as output would be:

`IssueID'  'UpTime'

32144          24

How I calculated this was taking the first issue activity record and recording the date and time.  Then I found the first activity that has " to Hold" in it and perform a datediff on the two dates, that gives me how long it was in 'up time'.  I don't calculate the time that it was in a 'down' state.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often done using aggregates to get the `min` timestamp (when issue was created) and `max` (when it was closed). If you want to consider only specific state changes (`Notes` in your Fiddle) you can use `CASE` to filter it:

```
SELECT min(ActivityDate) start_time
     , max(CASE WHEN Notes='Sub Status has changed from Work In Progress to Closed.' THEN ActivityDate END) close_time
 FROM IssueActivities
GROUP BY IssueId
```

This is usually easier to understand using [the `filter` clause](http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter), which SQL Server (nor SQLite) doesn't support. However, have a look just for understanding:

```
SELECT min(ActivityDate) start_time
     , max(ActivityDate) FILTER (WHERE Notes='Sub Status has changed from Work In Progress to Closed.') close_time
 FROM IssueActivities
GROUP BY IssueId
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f56bd/4

Building the difference to get the duration should be easy enough.

Obviously, this will only work for a single duration (e.g. if the issue is re-opened, it will cover the time while it was closed too).